# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException when executing jar in code

Tags: java, jar, maven-2, classloader

I've got a problem when trying to execute specific jar files in code. My objective was to create GUI application (wizard) in which user selects various xml files, selects a jar file to execute and provide it with input xml.

To execute jar, I use this code:

    `1: URL[] urls = fillUrls();
    2: loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    3: Class<?> cls = loader.loadClass(className);
    4: Method execute = cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Properties.class, 
                     StringBuffer.class, StringBuffer.class, IContext.class);
    // method name is declared as:
    // private final String methodName = "execute";`

Method **fillUrls** on line 1 returns URLs of executed jar and other libraries which are required by executed jar to run. If omitted, line 3 would throw an exception. When method reaches line 4 the java.lang.NoSuchMethodException is thrown.

Strange thing is, that the executed class in jar implements an interface so there is no chance that there will be no such method. And to make it more interesting, jar files I used for testing runs perfectly, jars supplied by other guys don't...

So could it be something wrong with my code, or is it the problem how are the jar files exported? And is there any way to prove it? Exported jar are from maven2 project.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

loader = new URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);

Comment: how is that supposed to help? It only produces "URLClassLoader.newInstance cannot be resolved to a type" error. And besides, the cause of my problem is on line 4, I suppose.

Comment: newInstance is a static method of URLCLassloader, and is calling the securityManager.checkPackageAccess if you have a security manager installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
cls.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, Properties.class, 
                     StringBuffer.class, StringBuffer.class, IContext.class);
```

throws `NoSuchMethodException` if a matching method is not found.

There is no such method in the `Class` (Class name you provided) with the given method name and method's formal parameter types 
`(Properties.class,StringBuffer.class, StringBuffer.class, IContext.class)` in declared order.

Comment: well, the method should be in the connector, but I'm not so sure about the order of formal parameters.

Comment: Can you please check the class source for the method?

Comment: I just found out, that they reworked the class. Now it extends two other classes instead of implementing resource. But both classes are added to the classloader. Does it change way how I should execute the method?

Comment: That won't be a problem, unless there is an impact in method signature

Comment: well, it's working now and the problem was in getDeclaredMethod(). With getMethod() it works. According to this: [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/366914/java/java/getMethod-getDeclaredMethod) getDeclardedMethod() won't work with inherited methods which is my case...